# Linux cross-compiler for Cygwin -- not able to find the Linux Cygwin compiler tool chain online

Tags: linux, gcc, g++, cygwin, cross-compiling

I have installed Cygwin and followed the necessary steps to install the right packages to allow for Linux cross-compilation on Windows. 
More info on procedure here [Compiling Linux binaries (x86/x86-64) under Windows](http://metamod-p.sourceforge.net/cross-compiling.on.windows.for.linux.html)

However, I am not able to obtain the actual Linux compiler tools from the source above, or anywhere online (after hours of searching). The download to the Linux cross-compiler for Cygwin points to [Metamod-P](http://metamod-p-1.21p37-windows.zip%20(57.6%20kB)), I wonder what Metamod-P is.

How or where can I get the required Linux cross-compiler for cygwin?

Comment: Why on Earth would anyone do that? Cross-compiling for Linux on Windows is like towing your totally functional car with a bicycle.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker. I have a good reason for doing so. I need to do quick code error fixes on my basic Windows dev machine. Details of it is too long to mention here. If you have an answer please provide it. Thanks.

Comment: If I had an answer, I'd offer it. You can't SSH into a Linux machine somewhere? Or build a VM? Or dual boot?

Comment: Those are exactly the things I am trying to avoid. I need a quick code check/debug environment for things as simple as syntax check during compile. #fast. Don't need to have to SSH or reboot, start VM, transfer source files etc, for simple "sanity check" compilation.

Comment: I get that. I just don't know of any development tools or environments on Windows but not Linux that would make using Windows worthwhile. Maybe you do.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [Cygwin Ports](http://cygwinports.org/) repository contains cross-compilers for i686, x86_64, armv7hl, and aarch64 GNU/Linux targets.  Look for the `linux-*-gcc-*` packages under the `Devel` category.

Comment: you are a hero. I have installed the tools, thanks! Now what is the actual name of the cross-compiler? Need to update my make file to use it. `linux-x86_64-gcc-g++` or just `linux-g++`? i have tried both, none can be found.

Comment: PROBLEM SOLVED:
After install of cygwin linux cross-compiler tools as described by @Yaakov, the compiler I used was: `x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-gcc` or `x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-g++` for c or c++ projects respectively.

Comment: Hi nikk, i am following the same steps mentioned by yakkov here, https://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2012-06/msg00221.html . I am getting errors while compiling cross-binutils

Comment: Were you able to use Linux specific header files like dlfcn.h and sys/mman.h ?

Comment: the link seems to be dead as of today.