# What is the right package that should be added to cross compile for Linux when installing cygwin?

Tags: c++, linux, cygwin, x86-64, cross-compiling

I am trying to compile Linux binaries on Windows with Cygwin. I found [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28596403/linux-cross-compiler-for-cygwin-not-able-to-find-the-linux-cygwin-compiler-to/28598156) about the issue and best answer to the topic says that `linux-*-gcc-*` packages under `Devel` category (Cygwin Ports repository) should be added. However, I am not able to find such packages under Devel category.

How can I get the right packages for Cygwin to cross compile Linux binaries on Windows? Or, is there any other recommendations about cross compiling for Linux on Windows?

Comment: Cross compiling is usually a hassle to get set up and it's error prone since you often cannot easily run your unit tests. I'd propose setting up a build environment where you compile your code natively on the target platform (and also run your tests there). That's usually the path-of-least-resistance.

Comment: In particular if you are running windows 10 I suggest you use windows subsystem for linux, it uses actual linux (ELF) binaries and the compilers produce the same. I've done it in the past with cygwin but getting it to work was a massive pain.

Comment: I would also recommend WSL if that is available to you. Cross-compiling in Cygwin is painful and very slow. If WSL is not available to you, let us know.

Comment: Hi Chris, Unfortunately WSL is not an option for me. I use Windows 7 as host operating system.